# No rule to make target 'mesh2D.h', needed by 'all-am'

Tags: automake

I have the following project tree :

```
src
├── Converters
├── datamodel
```

Inside `datamodel/` I have a header that I want to include in a source cpp file inside `Converters/`.

However I get the following error :

```
No rule to make target 'mesh2D.h', needed by 'all-am'
```

This is my automake `Makefile.am` inside `Converters/`:

```
include $(top_srcdir)/adm_local/unix/make_common_start.am

AM_CPPFLAGS+=  \
-I$(top_srcdir)/src/datamodel

libSource_SOURCES=\
    source.cpp \
    source.h 

include_HEADERS=\
    mesh2D.h

SUBDIRS= 

include $(top_srcdir)/adm_local/unix/make_common_end.am
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the feeling that there's crucial information missing. Sure that the error comes from the makefile inside that dir (and not another, possibly main level)? What do the other makefile parts look like?
You *do* have somewhere a rule where that file is as dependency, but does not exist. Maybe it's also a path issue in the declared dependencies. In order to debug this, one will need the full project's source.

Comment: Actually before I added the new datamodel subdirectory, everything was fine. I juste need the Converters source files to compile against the new header from datamodel

Answer (score 0):

I would move the

```
include_HEADERS = mesh2D.h
```

line to `datamodel/Makefile.am` if you are using recursive make, or

```
include_HEADERS += %reldir%/mesh2D.h
```

to `datamodel/Makefile-files` if you use a single `Makefile.am` with per-directory includes or

```
include_HEADERS += datamodel/mesh2D.h
```

if you are using a single `Makefile.am` without per-directory includes.

Note that using `include_HEADERS` will install the `mesh2D.h` file into `/usr/local/include`. If `mesh2D.h` is just needed to compile your program, use `noinst_HEADERS` instead of `include_HEADERS` to include `mesh2D.h` in the distribution tarball (`make dist`) without installing it (`make install`).